ChatGoogleGenerativeAIError: Invalid argument provided to Gemini: 400 Please ensure that multiturn requests alternate between user and model
langchain_google_genai.chat_models.ChatGoogleGenerativeAIError: Invalid argument provided to Gemini: 400 Please ensure that multiturn requests alternate between user and model.
I want to create a conversational chat with website using gemini pro model with the help of langchain and streamlit
and I used to store the chat and again pass to the model as chat_history of text but it show me error.
I use for reference to create the website chat.--> https://github.com/alejandro-ao/chat-with-websites/blob/master/src/app.py
he use openAI.
import streamlit as st


# pip install streamlit langchain lanchain-openai beautifulsoup4 python-dotenv chromadb
from langchain_core.messages import AIMessage, HumanMessage
from langchain_community.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings, ChatOpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate, MessagesPlaceholder
from langchain.chains import create_history_aware_retriever, create_retrieval_chain
from langchain.chains.combine_documents import create_stuff_documents_chain


from langchain import PromptTemplate
from langchain import hub
from langchain.docstore.document import Document
from langchain.document_loaders import WebBaseLoader
from langchain.schema import StrOutputParser
from langchain.schema.prompt_template import format_document
from langchain.schema.runnable import RunnablePassthrough
from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
from langchain_google_genai import GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI


def get_vectorstore_from_url(url):
    loader  = WebBaseLoader(url)
    docs = loader.load()

    text_content = docs[0].page_content
    print(len(text_content))

    text_content_1 = text_content.split("code, audio, image and video.",1)[1]
    final_text = text_content_1.split("Cloud TPU v5p",1)[0]

    # Convert the text to LangChain's `Document` format
    docs =  [Document(page_content=final_text, metadata={"source": "local"})]

    # embedding the docs
    gemini_embeddings = GoogleGenerativeAIEmbeddings(model="models/embedding-001")

    # Save to disk
    vectorstore = Chroma.from_documents(
                     documents=docs,                 # Data
                     embedding=gemini_embeddings,    # Embedding model
                     persist_directory="./chroma_db" # Directory to save data
                     )
    
    # Load from disk
    vectorstore_disk = Chroma(
                        persist_directory="./chroma_db",       # Directory of db
                        embedding_function=gemini_embeddings   # Embedding model
                   )

    retriever = vectorstore_disk.as_retriever(search_kwargs={"k": 1})
    print(len(retriever.get_relevant_documents("MMLU")))
    
    return retriever

def get_context_retriver_chain(retriver):
    
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro",
                 temperature=0.7, top_p=0.85)
    
    retriver = retriver

    # Prompt template to query Gemini
    llm_prompt_template = """You are an assistant for question-answering tasks.
    Use the following context to answer the question.
    If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know.
    Use five sentences maximum and keep the answer concise.\n
    Question: {question} \nContext: {context} \nAnswer:"""

    llm_prompt = PromptTemplate.from_template(llm_prompt_template)

    print(llm_prompt)

    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
        ("user", "{input}"),
       ("user", "Given the above conversation, generate a search query to look up in order to get information relevant to the conversation")
    ])

    retriver_chain = create_history_aware_retriever(llm, retriver,prompt)

    return retriver_chain

def get_conversational_rag_chain(retriever_chain): 
    llm = ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro",
                 temperature=0.7, top_p=0.85)
    
    prompt = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
        ("system", "Answer the user's questions based on the below context:\n\n{context}"),
      MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
      ("user", "{input}"),
    ])

    stuff_documents_chain = create_stuff_documents_chain(llm, prompt)

    return create_retrieval_chain(retriever_chain, stuff_documents_chain)

    # Combine data from documents to readable string format.
def format_docs(docs):
    return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

def get_response(user_input):
    retriver_chain = get_context_retriver_chain(st.session_state.vector_store)
    conversation_rag_chain = get_conversational_rag_chain(retriver_chain)

    response = conversation_rag_chain.invoke({
        "chat_history": st.session_state.chat_history,
        "input": user_input
    })

    return response["answer"]
# rag_chain = (
#     {"context": retriever | format_docs, "question": RunnablePassthrough()}
#     | llm_prompt
#     | llm
#     | StrOutputParser()
# )

# rag_chain.invoke("any thing in this context ")


# App config
st.set_page_config(page_title =" Chat with websites", page_icon="")
st.title("Chat with websites")

#sidebar 
with st.sidebar:
    st.header("Settings")
    website_url = st.text_input ("Wbsite URL")

if website_url is None or website_url =="":
    st.info("Please enter a website URl")

else:
    #session state
    if "chat_history" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.chat_history = [
            AIMessage(content = "Hello, I am a bot. How can I help you?")

        ]
    if "vector_store" not in st.session_state:
        st.session_state.vector_store = get_vectorstore_from_url(website_url)

    # user input 
    user_query = st.chat_input("Type your message here...")
    if user_query is not None and user_query !="":
        response = get_response(user_query)
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(HumanMessage(content=user_query))
        st.session_state.chat_history.append(AIMessage(content = response))


The error message is slightly deceptive.
The complete rules for what can be sent to Gemini are:

The role must alternate between "user" (HumanMessage) and "model" (AIMessage). (If you're using functions, you can use a "function" (FunctionMessage or ToolMessage) instead of "user".)
The history must start with a "user" role. It looks like you're starting with AIMessage, which will create a "model" role.
The last thing sent must be a "user" (or "function") role message. This is usually done by sending the message, so it's kinda obvious, but it's one of the rules.

(There are also issues with SystemMessages, which Gemini didn't handle at all in older versions, and now handle using system_instruction. But that's a completely different story.)

I'm following this guide (https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/extraction_examples/) to send examples with my query to a Gemini model but the messages end up being structured to have the following order  HumanMessage - AIMessage - ToolMessage - HumanMessage - AIMessage - ToolMessage - etc.., so this is breaking when I'm running it with Gemini. If I just remove the ToolMessage parts I stop getting errors but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way to do it. Based on your answer, would a better fix be to add an AIMessage in between the Tool and Human messages?

Just in case you do have an answer to my above comment, I've posted a proper question here https://stackoverflow.com/q/79155250/8633026
