RAG Examples and Gemini: InvalidArgument:Please ensure that function call turn comes immediately after a user turn or after a function response turn
I'm following this guide (https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/extraction_examples) to send examples with my query to a Gemini model using langchain and ChatVertexAI. When I run extractor.invoke({"text": text, "examples": example_messages}) the model keeps retrying with the warning: InvalidArgument: 400 Please ensure that function call turn comes immediately after a user turn or after a function response turn. If I run invoke without the examples, the model runs as expected. Similarly, if I use a ChatOpenAI model, the model runs as expected with the examples.
As far as I can tell (e.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/78403270/8633026), for Gemini models the roles must alternate between 'user' and 'ai' roles, which I think is what is causing the issue. The example messages generated by following the tutorial end up being structured to have the following order HumanMessage - AIMessage - ToolMessage - HumanMessage - AIMessage - ToolMessage - etc..
My question is, what is the appropriate way to organise these example messages for Gemini?
If I just remove the ToolMessage parts I stop getting errors but I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way to do it. Maybe it would be a better fix be to add an AIMessage in between the Tool and Human messages?

I'm not sure what's changed but this issue seems to have resolved itself. I did update to langchain v 0.3 at some point recently, which may be related.

As you suggested, the Gemini API seems to assume that the first piece of Content (message in the conversation) will be from the user (role: "USER") and that the role alternates each turn (after each message). As a result, the API (as of Nov 5, 2024) also assumes that all odd indices (second message at index 1, fourth message at index 3, sixth message at index 5, etc.) are messages generated by the model (e.g., role: ASSISTANT responses, function calls, etc.). So it expects (as of Nov 5, 2024) the function response (Content containing FunctionResponsePart) to be in an even index — since function responses are not generated by the model.
I believe this assumption will not be made in future releases.
For now, I recommend ensuring that the function response (output for the function call) exists in an even index.

Thanks, but I feel like you've just reworded my question without providing an answer. I know that putting the function response/tool messages and human messages in even indices will remove the error message but the question is how exactly to do this as I currently have 3 things to fit in two places
